# How to copy a bitmap to an image with transparency based on alpha

Tags: c#, bitmap, transparency, alpha

I'm writing in C# for WPF. I have a bitmap that I want to blit to the screen. Here's what I'm doing now (which creates a nice blit with white as the transparent color):

```
        // Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
        UnitImageBMP.MakeTransparent(System.Drawing.Color.White);

        // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
        g.DrawImage(RotatedBMP,
            BlueArmy[index].LocationX - (RotatedBMP.Width / 2),
            BlueArmy[index].LocationY - (RotatedBMP.Height / 2),
            RotatedBMP.Width,
            RotatedBMP.Height);
```

This works fine. But now I want to make the blitted image 'fade' based, presumably, on the alpha channel (actually, I need to create a number of 'fade' steps).

I haven't found this question covered with WPF, bitmap to an image. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Because the effect I'm looking for seems unclear, I found this image. The middle image shows the effect that I'm looking for. 
[image]

Comment: _transparency based on alpha_ As Alpha __is__ the transparency your question is quite unclear..

Comment: I want the blitted image to be faded; perhaps using a ColorMatrix? Blending the image with background to some extent.